# Straight away show keyboard in editText when checkBox get checked

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext, spinner

So I have an `editText` , `checkbox` and `spinner` in `activity`.

When `checkbox` is checked, `editText` will shown and `spinner` will be hidden.

```
 public void addListenerOnTo() // for checkbox
    {

        checkBoxTo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    travelTo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // spinner
                    addTo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // editText

                } else {
                    travelTo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    addTo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I type the input straight away after the `checkbox` is checked without pressing the `editText` to show the keyboard? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to open keyboard for editing EditText when click button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815696/android-how-to-open-keyboard-for-editing-edittext-when-click-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code after `addTo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(InputEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Answer (score 1):

**This can be simply achieved by setting the focus on the edittext and then making the soft keyboard visible forcefully !**

```
  public void addListenerOnTo() // for checkbox
        {

            checkBoxTo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        travelTo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // spinner
                        addTo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // editText

    // add this line to make the keyboard visible 

addTo.requestFocus();

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

                    } else {
                        travelTo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        addTo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Let me know if this works! :)